# Cannot reference column outside of union

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I'm implementing role based access control in my app, and need to optionally include an extra row if a role inherits another.

I tried using a union with a where clause inside my subquery. I am using postgres.

Using knex, my code looks like this:

```
export const rowToJSONArray = (query: QueryBuilder, column: string) => {
  const id = randomBytes(8).toString("hex")

  return `
    ARRAY(
      SELECT
        row_to_json("${id}")
      FROM ( ${query.toQuery()} ) as "${id}"
    ) as "${column}"
  `
}

export const getPermissionListQuery = (as = "Role_permissions") => {
  const subquery = db
    .select("name", "type")
    .from("Permissions")
    .join("RolePermissions", "RolePermissions.permissionId", "Permissions.id")
    .where("RolePermissions.roleId", db.raw(`"Roles"."id"`))

  return rowToJSONArray(subquery, as)
}

export const getUserRoleListQuery = (withPermissions = false) => {
  const subquery = db
    .select("name")
    .from("Roles")
    .leftJoin("UserRoles", "Roles.id", "UserRoles.roleId")
    .where("UserRoles.userId", db.raw(`"Users"."id"`))
    .orWhere("Roles.id", db.raw(DEFAULT_ROLE_ID)) // imply the default role always
    .union(query => {
      query
        .select("name")
        .from("Roles as UnionRoles")
        .where("Roles.inheritId", "UnionRoles.id")
    })
    .orderBy("Roles.priority", "asc")

  if (withPermissions) {
    subquery.select(db.raw(getPermissionListQuery("permissions")))
  }

  return rowToJSONArray(subquery, "User_roles")
}
```

So, I expect that if in theory Role 1 inherits Role 2, if a user has Role 1, then Role 2 will also be included in the list of roles that the user has.

However, instead I am getting this error:

```
error: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "Roles"
hint: 'Perhaps you meant to reference the table alias "UnionRoles".'
```

Comment: How deep is roles inheritance, just two levels or it is not limited?

Comment: Right now it's just a simple `inheritsId` on the role row itself, which references another role. So only as deep as how many roles are being inherited in a chain.

Comment: I see, it's not limited. So if a user is assigned to Role1, and Role1 inherits Role2, Role2 inherits Role3, .. you want all Role1, Role2, Role3, .. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the generated Postgres query should look like.
Test data

```
create table Roles (
  id int not null
  ,inheritId int
  ,"name" varchar(50) 
);    
insert into Roles(id, inheritId, "name")
values
  (1,null,'Role 1')
 ,(2,1,'Role 2')
 ,(3,2,'Role 3')
 ,(4,2,'Role 4');

create table Users (
  id int not null
  ,"name" varchar(50) 
);
insert into Users(id, "name")
values
  (1,'User A')
 ,(2,'User B')
 ,(3,'User C')
 ,(4,'User D');

create table UserRoles (
  userId int not null
  ,roleId int not null
);
insert into UserRoles(userId, roleId)
values
   (1,1)
  ,(1,4)
  ,(3,3) -- changed it
  ,(4,4);
```

Two queries using the same recursive CTE. CTE traverses the inheritance chain to find all effective roles starting with an arbitrary role.

Users + effective roles:

```
with recursive r as(
   select id as baseid, inheritid, "name"
   from Roles
   union all
   select r.baseid, c.inheritid, c."name"
   from r
   join Roles c on c.Id = r.inheritid
)
select distinct u."name" as userName, r."name"  as roleName
from users u 
join userRoles ur on ur.userId = u.Id
join r on r.baseId = ur.roleId
order by u."name", r."name";
```

Output

```
username    rolename
User A  Role 1
User A  Role 2
User A  Role 4
User C  Role 1
User C  Role 2
User C  Role 3
User D  Role 1
User D  Role 2
User D  Role 4
```

Effective role names for a user

```
with recursive r as(
   select id as baseid,  inheritid, "name"
   from Roles
   union all
   select r.baseid,  c.inheritid, c."name"
   from r
   join Roles c on c.Id = r.inheritid
)
select distinct r."name"
from userRoles ur
join r on r.baseId = ur.roleId
where ur.userId=3
order by r."name";
```

Output

```
name
Role 1
Role 2
Role 3
```

I'm no so fluent in Knex, hope this will help you to build your query in a right way.

**EDIT**
Adding permissions

```
create table Permissions (
    id int
   ,"name" varchar(50) 
   ,"type" varchar(50) 
);

insert into Permissions (id, "name", "type")
values 
     (1, 'pm1', 'ptype1')
    ,(2, 'pm2', 'ptype1')
    ,(3, 'pm3', 'ptype2')
    ,(4, 'pm4', 'ptype2');

create table RolePermissions(
   permissionId int not null
  ,roleId int not null
);
insert into RolePermissions(permissionId, roleId)
values 
     (1, 1)  
    ,(2, 1)  
    ,(1, 3)  
    ,(2, 3)
    ,(3, 3)
    ,(2, 4)
    ,(4, 4);
```

Effective permissions for a user. Note `effectiveId` of the role which was not needed in previous queries as we used only role name, role's `"Name"` can be omitted here.

```
with recursive r as(
   select id as baseid, id as effectiveId, inheritid, "name"
   from Roles
   union all
   select r.baseid, c.id, c.inheritid, c."name"
   from r
   join Roles c on c.Id = r.inheritid
)
select distinct p."name" permissionName
   , p."type" permissionType
from userRoles ur
join r on r.baseId = ur.roleId
join RolePermissions rp on r.EffectiveId = rp.roleId
join Permissions p on rp.permissionId = p.id
where ur.userId=3
order by p."name";
```

Returns

```
permissionname  permissiontype
pm1 ptype1
pm2 ptype1
pm3 ptype2
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=76cac47ecbd7e90e778656365fd1d8f7)

You may wish to change `select` list and `order by` clause as needed.

Comment: Would it be possible to use the permission subquery that adds a permission array to each role, too?

Comment: @SebastianOlsen Yes, if you can share  permissions  table schema, i can add it to the query.

Comment: I've added it to the question.

Comment: So I tried replicating your code using knex, and I got it to run. However, the query doesn't actually include the inherited roles for some reason. I've made a pastebin with the generated query: https://pastebin.com/ehkxxVA4

Comment: I think I see why this isn't working. Your code assumes Role 2 will inherit Role 1, so when Role 1 is received, Role 2 will be too. But that's not what I want. I want Role 2 to be included if Role 1 has its inheritId set to Role 2's id.

Comment: @SebastianOlsen, I reversed  inheritace order in CTEs. Is it what you need?

Comment: Yes, almost. I'm just struggling adding my permission subquery into the mix. Unfortunately I cannot use a CTE for the permissions. It needs to be the subquery in my code. For some reason, every inherited role has the same baseid, which makes the set of permissions in the result the same as the parent role, which is wrong.

Comment: As you need  id of the effective role for further join with `RolePermissions` you should use the last query in my answer, with `effectiveId` column in CTE. See  the fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4fd3736f7f02ccd39c2aae4e43d8158e which is your query pastebin.com/rzbuapcu  adapted to the test data i have (missing columns removed).